# Oracle select only one non duplicates in 2 tables query

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I have a 2 tables

a) normalize table on col1 unique value

```
col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
10    j     u    c   z
20    r     y    b   k
```

b) table have multiple values of col1  From a

```
col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
10    l   m     k   j
10    3   4     5   7
10    b   v     c   b
20    a   s     d   c
```

when I run my query my result show multiple entries form table b  .. I nee to group by col1 but grouping show a message ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

```
Select cec.CLAIMNUM , cec.CLAIMNUM, cec.CLAIMID, cec.PROVIDERID, cec.PHYSICIANNAME,cec.PATIENTID ,cec.PATIENTFIRSTNAME || ' '||cec.PATIENTLASTNAME , cec.TOTALCHARGES , 
(Select Sum(TO_NUMBER (VALUESTRING)) from PRICINGMSGS pr where pr.CLAIMNUM = cec.CLAIMNUM and errorcode = 610000) as UCR,  
(SELECT Sum(SUBSTR(VALUESTRING, INSTR(VALUESTRING, '|')+1 ) )
FROM PRICINGMSGS p  where p.CLAIMNUM =cec.CLAIMNUM and errorcode = 610001)AS Medicare

 from CECLAIMS cec ,PRICINGMSGS price where 
 cec.CLAIMNUM = price.CLAIMNUM and
 cec.ACCTNUMBER = price.ACCTNUMBER and
cec.ACCTNUMBER ='TEST0001'   
group by cec.CLAIMNUM
```

Comment: sorry i typed query on search

Comment: You have to mention all column names in group by...plz see this link
https://www.oracletutorial.com/?s=group+by

Comment: provide expected output,do you need group by on Col1 and need all the column from table 2

Answer (score 1):

In your query, You are using columns other than `cec.claimnum` (which is in `group by`) in select clause.

Remember one rule, if your are using `group by` in your query then you can only use `columns` directly in `select` clause which are used in `group by`. All other columns must be used with `aggregate` function.

```
SELECT COL1, 
       COL2, 
       AGGREGATE_FUNCTION(COL3) AS COL3,
       ...
  FROM YOUR TABLE
 GROUP BY COL1, COL2
```

Cheers!!